# Python Poker Hand Comparison Progam

Tags: python, playing-cards

I recently started learning Python and the first program I've made is a program to determine the best 5 card hand from seven total cards and then to be able to compare two different hands to determine which would win. I just wanted to ask if you would be able to have a look at it and give me any thoughts on how I could improve either this program or just my coding in general. I'll put one of the code blocks down below and link to the full program.

Link to [full program](https://github.com/Doug160516/Poker-hand-comparison-/tree/5ffcbc3da7ce501d195fb1e78ef8037354b3a973).

```
def player_hand_value_check(hand):
    #to keep checking until the highest hand is found
    has_hand=False
    #to assign numerical value to hand so it can be compared in other function
    player_hand_type=""
    #Sorting hand by value
    hand.sort(key=lambda hand:hand.value)
    global player_hand_value, player_hand, player_hand_string
    
    
    #putting
    while has_hand==False:    
        #straight/royal flush check
        straight_flush_hand=[]
        straight_flush_suit_list=[]
        #getting counter of suits in hand
        for cards in hand:
            straight_flush_suit_list.append(cards.suit)
        straight_flush_suit_counter=Counter(straight_flush_suit_list)
        #single suit hand
        for cards in hand:
            if straight_flush_suit_counter[cards.suit]>=5:
                straight_flush_hand.append(cards)
            #royal flush check, using try in case flush_hand isn't long enough
        
        straight_flush_hand.sort(key=lambda straight_flush_hand:straight_flush_hand.value)
        try:
            if straight_flush_hand[-5].value==10 and straight_flush_hand[-4].value==11 and straight_flush_hand[-3].value==12 and straight_flush_hand[-2].value==13 and straight_flush_hand[-1].value==14:
                player_hand_type="Royal Flush"
                player_hand_value=hand_rankings[player_hand_type]
                #pop so it only displays appropriate cards
                if len(straight_flush_hand)==6:
                    straight_flush_hand.pop(0)
                elif len(straight_flush_hand)==7:
                    straight_flush_hand.pop(0)
                    straight_flush_hand.pop(0)
                else:
                    pass
                has_hand=True
                player_hand=straight_flush_hand
                global player_has_royal_flush
                player_has_royal_flush=True
                player_hand_string=f"Royal Flush-{straight_flush_hand[0].suit}"
                
                break
        except IndexError:
            pass
        else:
            pass
        #high end straight flush
        try:
            if straight_flush_hand[-1].value==straight_flush_hand[-2].value+1 and straight_flush_hand[-2].value==straight_flush_hand[-3].value+1 and straight_flush_hand[-3].value==straight_flush_hand[-4].value+1 and straight_flush_hand[-4].value==straight_flush_hand[-5].value+1:
                player_hand_type="Straight Flush"
                player_hand_value=hand_rankings[player_hand_type]
                #pop so it only displays appropriate cards
                if len(straight_flush_hand)==6:
                    straight_flush_hand.pop(0)
                elif len(straight_flush_hand)==7:
                    straight_flush_hand.pop(0)
                    straight_flush_hand.pop(0)
                #change global variables for opponent comparison function
                global player_has_straight_flush, player_straight_flush_value
                player_has_straight_flush=True
                player_straight_flush_value=straight_flush_hand[-1].value
                has_hand=True
                player_hand=straight_flush_hand
                player_hand_string=f"Straight Flush-{straight_flush_hand[-1].rank} High-{straight_flush_hand[-1].suit}"
                break
        except IndexError:
            pass
        else:
            pass
        #mid range straight flush
        try:
            if straight_flush_hand[-2].value==straight_flush_hand[-3].value+1 and straight_flush_hand[-3].value==straight_flush_hand[-4].value+1 and straight_flush_hand[-4].value==straight_flush_hand[-5].value+1 and straight_flush_hand[-5].value==straight_flush_hand[-6].value+1:
                player_hand_type="Straight Flush"
                player_hand_value=hand_rankings[player_hand_type]
                #pop so it only displays appropriate cards
                if len(straight_flush_hand)==6:
                    straight_flush_hand.pop(-1)
                elif len(straight_flush_hand)==7:
                    straight_flush_hand.pop(-1)
                    straight_flush_hand.pop(0)
                player_has_straight_flush=True
                player_straight_flush_value=straight_flush_hand[-2].value
                has_hand=True
                player_hand=straight_flush_hand
                player_hand_string=f"Straight Flush-{straight_flush_hand[-2].rank} High-{straight_flush_hand[-2].suit}"
                break
        except IndexError:
            pass
        else:
            pass
        #low range straight flush
        try:
            if straight_flush_hand[-3].value==straight_flush_hand[-4].value+1 and straight_flush_hand[-4].value==straight_flush_hand[-5].value+1 and straight_flush_hand[-5].value==straight_flush_hand[-6].value+1 and straight_flush_hand[-6].value==straight_flush_hand[-7].value+1:
                player_hand_type="Straight Flush"
                player_hand_value=hand_rankings[player_hand_type]
                #pop so it only displays appropriate cards
                if len(straight_flush_hand)==6:
                    straight_flush_hand.pop(-1)
                elif len(straight_flush_hand)==7:
                    straight_flush_hand.pop(-1)
                    straight_flush_hand.pop(-1)
                player_has_straight_flush=True
                player_straight_flush_value=straight_flush_hand[-3].value
                has_hand=True
                player_hand=straight_flush_hand
                player_hand_string=f"Straight Flush-{straight_flush_hand[-3].rank} High-{straight_flush_hand[-3].suit}"
                break
        except IndexError:
            pass
        else:
            pass
        #ace low straight flush
        try:
            if straight_flush_hand[-1].value==14 and straight_flush_hand[0].value==2 and straight_flush_hand[1].value==3 and straight_flush_hand[2].value==4 and straight_flush_hand[3].value==5: 
                player_hand_type="Straight Flush"
                player_hand_value=hand_rankings[player_hand_type]
                #pop so it only displays appropriate cards
                if len(straight_flush_hand)==6:
                    straight_flush_hand.pop(-2)
                elif len(straight_flush_hand)==7:
                    straight_flush_hand.pop(-2)
                    straight_flush_hand.pop(-2)
                player_has_straight_flush=True
                player_straight_flush_value=straight_flush_hand[3].value
                has_hand=True
                player_hand=straight_flush_hand
                player_hand_string=f"Straight Flush-{straight_flush_hand[3].rank} High-{straight_flush_hand[3].suit}"
                break
        except IndexError:
            pass
        else:
            pass
        #four of a kind, sort by rank, count rank, if 4 in rank, append to new list, add all others to new list, sort that list and attach [-1] to four of a kind hand and player kicker is also[-1]
        hand.sort(key=lambda hand:hand.value)
        four_of_a_kind_hand=[]
        four_of_a_kind_kickers=[]
        four_kind_list=[]
        for cards in hand:
            four_kind_list.append(cards.value)
        #compare to cards in hand
        four_kind_value_counter=Counter(four_kind_list)
        #assign four of a kind and kickers to seperate hand
        for cards in hand:
            if four_kind_value_counter[cards.value]<4:
                four_of_a_kind_kickers.append(cards)
            elif four_kind_value_counter[cards.value]==4:
                four_of_a_kind_hand.append(cards)
            else:
                pass
                #check for length of four_of_a_kind_hand
        if len(four_of_a_kind_hand)>0:
            player_hand_type="Four of a Kind"
            player_hand_value=hand_rankings[player_hand_type]
            #change global variables for opponent comparison function
            global player_has_four_of_a_kind, player_four_of_a_kind_kicker,player_four_of_a_kind_value
            #sorting kickers list and appending -1 value
            four_of_a_kind_kickers.sort(key=lambda hand:hand.value)
            four_of_a_kind_hand.append(four_of_a_kind_kickers[-1])
            player_has_four_of_a_kind=True
            player_four_of_a_kind_value=four_of_a_kind_hand[0].value
            player_four_of_a_kind_kicker=four_of_a_kind_kickers[-1].value
            has_hand=True
            player_hand=four_of_a_kind_hand
            player_hand_string=f"Four of a Kind-{four_of_a_kind_hand[0].rank}s"
            break
            #probably not needed but just for readability
        else: 
            pass
        #full house check
        #sorted by rank, values added to test list, if value counter is 3 added to full house 3, if 2 added to full house pair, sorted then for loop using -1 value
        full_house_list=[]
        full_house_threes=[]
        full_house_pairs=[]
        full_house_hand=[]
            
        for cards in hand:
            full_house_list.append(cards.value)
        #not sure if its a problem to reuse value counter name
        full_house_value_counter=Counter(full_house_list)
        #for loop to add to threes and pairs list
        for cards in hand:
            if full_house_value_counter[cards.value]==3:
                full_house_threes.append(cards)
            elif full_house_value_counter[cards.value]==2:
                full_house_pairs.append(cards)
            else:
                pass
            #in case multiple 3 will append lower 3 to pair list
        if len(full_house_threes)>3:
            full_house_threes.sort(key=lambda full_house_threes:full_house_threes.value)
            full_house_pairs.append(full_house_threes[0])
            full_house_pairs.append(full_house_threes[1])
        else:
            pass
                
            #if 3 list and pair list aren't empty then full house is true
        if len(full_house_threes)>0 and len(full_house_pairs)>0: 
            full_house_threes.sort(key=lambda full_house_threes:full_house_threes.value)
            full_house_pairs.sort(key=lambda full_house_pairs:full_house_pairs.value)
            full_house_hand.append(full_house_threes[-1])
            full_house_hand.append(full_house_threes[-2])
            full_house_hand.append(full_house_threes[-3])
            full_house_hand.append(full_house_pairs[-1])
            full_house_hand.append(full_house_pairs[-2])
            player_hand_type="Full House"
            player_hand_value=hand_rankings[player_hand_type]
            global player_has_full_house, player_full_house_value, player_full_house_kicker
            player_has_full_house=True
            player_full_house_value=full_house_threes[-1].value
            player_full_house_kicker=full_house_pairs[-1].value
            has_hand=True
            player_hand=full_house_hand
            player_hand_string=f"Full House-{full_house_threes[-1].rank}s over {full_house_pairs[-1].rank}s"
            break
        else:
            #problem with flush seems to start here
            pass
        #Flush check, should be similar to royal flush
        #finally fixed, issue was try except for straight flush didn't have an else statement
        flush_hand=[]
        flush_suit_list=[]
        for cards in hand:
            flush_suit_list.append(cards.suit)
        flush_suit_counter=Counter(flush_suit_list)
        #single suit hand
        for cards in hand:
            if flush_suit_counter[cards.suit]>=5:
                flush_hand.append(cards)
        #checking for flush    
        if len(flush_hand)>=5:
            flush_hand.sort(key=lambda flush_hand:flush_hand.value)
            #popping flush_hand appropriately
            if len(flush_hand)==6:
                flush_hand.pop(0)
            elif len(flush_hand)==7:
                flush_hand.pop(0)
                flush_hand.pop(0)
            else:
                pass
            player_hand_type="Flush"
            player_hand_value=hand_rankings[player_hand_type]
            flush_hand.sort(key=lambda flush_hand:flush_hand.value)
            global player_has_flush, player_flush_value
            player_has_flush=True
            player_flush_value=[flush_hand[-1].value,flush_hand[-2].value,flush_hand[-3].value,flush_hand[-4].value,flush_hand[-5].value,]
            has_hand=True
            player_hand=flush_hand
            player_hand_string=f"{flush_hand[-1].suit} Flush-{flush_hand[-1].rank}"
            break
                            
        else:
            pass
        
        #straight check
        #remove code isn't working but straight works with no double ranks
        straight_hand=[]
        for cards in hand:
            straight_hand.append(cards)
        straight_list=[]
        straight_counter=Counter(straight_list)
        for cards in straight_hand:
            straight_list.append(cards.rank)
        straight_counter=Counter(straight_list)
        for cards in straight_hand:
            if straight_counter[cards.rank]>1:
                straight_hand.remove(cards)
        straight_hand.sort(key=lambda straight_hand:straight_hand.value)
        #high end straight, code the same as for straight flush
        try:
            if straight_hand[-1].value==straight_hand[-2].value+1 and straight_hand[-2].value==straight_hand[-3].value+1 and straight_hand[-3].value==straight_hand[-4].value+1 and straight_hand[-4].value==straight_hand[-5].value+1:
                    player_hand_type="Straight"
                    player_hand_value=hand_rankings[player_hand_type]
                    #pop so it only displays appropriate cards
                    if len(straight_hand)==6:
                        straight_hand.pop(0)
                    elif len(straight_hand)==7:
                        straight_hand.pop(0)
                        straight_hand.pop(0)
                    else:
                        pass
                    global player_has_straight, player_straight_value
                    player_has_straight=True
                    player_straight_value=straight_hand[-1].value
                    has_hand=True
                    player_hand=straight_hand
                    player_hand_string=f"Straight-{straight_hand[-1].rank} High"
                    break
        except IndexError:
            pass
        else:
            pass
        #mid range straight,
        try:
            if straight_hand[-2].value==straight_hand[-3].value+1 and straight_hand[-3].value==straight_hand[-4].value+1 and straight_hand[-4].value==straight_hand[-5].value+1 and straight_hand[-5].value==straight_hand[-6].value+1:
                    player_hand_type="Straight"
                    player_hand_value=hand_rankings[player_hand_type]
                    #pop so it only displays appropriate cards
                    if len(straight_hand)==6:
                        straight_hand.pop(-1)
                    elif len(straight_hand)==7:
                        straight_hand.pop(-1)
                        straight_hand.pop(0)
                    else:
                        pass
                    player_has_straight=True
                    player_straight_value=straight_hand[-1].value
                    has_hand=True
                    player_hand=straight_hand
                    player_hand_string=f"Straight-{straight_hand[-1].rank} High"
                    break
        except IndexError:
            pass
        else:
            pass
        #low end straight
        try:
            if straight_hand[-3].value==straight_hand[-4].value+1 and straight_hand[-4].value==straight_hand[-5].value+1 and straight_hand[-5].value==straight_hand[-6].value+1 and straight_hand[-6].value==straight_hand[-7].value+1:
                    player_hand_type="Straight"
                    player_hand_value=hand_rankings[player_hand_type]
                    #pop so it only displays appropriate cards
                    if len(straight_hand)==6:
                        straight_hand.pop(-1)
                    elif len(straight_flush_hand)==7:
                        straight_hand.pop(-1)
                        straight_hand.pop(-1)
                    player_has_straight=True
                    player_straight_value=straight_hand[-1].value
                    has_hand=True
                    player_hand=straight_hand
                    player_hand_string=f"Straight-{straight_hand[-1].rank} High"
                    break
        except IndexError:
            pass
        else:
            pass
        try:
            if straight_hand[-1].value==14 and straight_hand[0].value==2 and straight_hand[1].value==3 and straight_hand[2].value==4 and straight_hand[3].value==5: 
                player_hand_type="Straight"
                player_hand_value=hand_rankings[player_hand_type]
                #pop so it only displays appropriate cards
                if len(straight_hand)==6:
                    straight_hand.pop(-2)
                elif len(straight_hand)==7:
                    straight_hand.pop(-2)
                    straight_hand.pop(-2)
                player_has_straight=True
                player_straight_value=straight_hand[3].value
                has_hand=True
                player_hand=straight_hand
                player_hand_string=f"Straight-{straight_hand[3].rank} High"
                break
        except IndexError:
            pass
        else:
            pass
        #three of a kind check, getting * try and fix, actually was related to straight_hand=hand, obviously they affect each other
        #list to hold all values
        three_kind_list=[]
        #list to find triple cards
        three_kind_threes=[]
        #final hand to return
        three_kind_hand=[]
        #list to hold potential kickers
        three_kind_kickers=[]
        #append to three kind hand
        for cards in hand:
            three_kind_list.append(cards.value)
        #counter for values
        three_kind_value_counter=Counter(three_kind_list)
        for cards in hand:
            if three_kind_value_counter[cards.value]==3:
                three_kind_threes.append(cards)
            elif three_kind_value_counter[cards.value]<3:
                three_kind_kickers.append(cards)
            else:
                pass
        #don't need to check for multiple threes as it should have been caught by full house check
        if len(three_kind_threes)>0:
            three_kind_hand.append(three_kind_threes[0])
            three_kind_hand.append(three_kind_threes[1])
            three_kind_hand.append(three_kind_threes[2])
            three_kind_kickers.sort(key=lambda three_kind_kickers:three_kind_kickers.value)
            three_kind_hand.append(three_kind_kickers[-1])
            three_kind_hand.append(three_kind_kickers[-2])
            player_hand_type="Three of a Kind"
            player_hand_value=hand_rankings[player_hand_type]
            global player_has_three_kind, player_three_kind_value, player_three_kind_kickers
            player_has_three_kind=True
            player_three_kind_value=three_kind_threes[-1].value
            player_three_kind_kickers=[three_kind_kickers[-1].value,three_kind_kickers[-2].value]
            has_hand=True
            player_hand=three_kind_hand
            player_hand_string=f"Three of a kind-{three_kind_threes[0].rank}s"
            break
        else:
            pass
        #two pair check
        #list to hold all values
        two_pair_list=[]
        #list to hold paired hands
        two_pair_pairs=[]
        #list to hold potential kickers
        two_pair_kickers=[]
        #final hand to return
        two_pair_hand=[]
        
        for cards in hand:
            two_pair_list.append(cards.value)
        #counter for values
        two_pair_value_counter=Counter(two_pair_list)
        for cards in hand:
            if two_pair_value_counter[cards.value]==2:
                two_pair_pairs.append(cards)
            elif two_pair_value_counter[cards.value]==1:
                two_pair_kickers.append(cards)
            else:
                pass
        #puts a potential third pair back in with kickers
        if len(two_pair_pairs)>=4:
            two_pair_pairs.sort(key=lambda two_pair_pairs:two_pair_pairs.value)
            if len(two_pair_pairs)>4:
                two_pair_kickers.append(two_pair_pairs[0])
                two_pair_kickers.append(two_pair_pairs[1])
            else:
                pass
            two_pair_kickers.sort(key=lambda two_pair_kickers:two_pair_kickers.value)
            two_pair_hand.append(two_pair_pairs[-1])
            two_pair_hand.append(two_pair_pairs[-2])
            two_pair_hand.append(two_pair_pairs[-3])
            two_pair_hand.append(two_pair_pairs[-4])
            two_pair_hand.append(two_pair_kickers[-1])
            player_hand_type="Two Pair"
            player_hand_value=hand_rankings[player_hand_type]
            global player_has_two_pair, player_two_pair_value, player_two_pair_kicker
            player_has_two_pair=True
            player_two_pair_value=[two_pair_pairs[-1].value,two_pair_pairs[-3].value]
            player_two_pair_kicker=two_pair_kickers[-1].value
            has_hand=True
            player_hand=two_pair_hand
            player_hand_string=f"Two Pair-{two_pair_pairs[-1].rank}s and {two_pair_pairs[-3].rank}s"
            break
        else:
            pass
        #pair check
        #list to hold all values
        pair_list=[]
        #list to hold pair
        pair_pair=[]
        #list to hold kickers
        pair_kickers=[]
        #final hand to return
        pair_hand=[]
        
        #append values to list
        for cards in hand:
            pair_list.append(cards.value)
        #counter for values
        pair_value_counter=Counter(pair_list)
        #append pairs and kickers to appropriate lists, else statement might have been sufficient but I'll use an elif for readability
        for cards in hand:
            if pair_value_counter[cards.value]==2:
                pair_pair.append(cards)
            elif pair_value_counter[cards.value]==1:
                pair_kickers.append(cards)
            else:
                pass
        if len(pair_pair)==2:
            pair_kickers.sort(key=lambda pair_kickers:pair_kickers.value)
            pair_hand.append(pair_pair[0])
            pair_hand.append(pair_pair[1])
            if len(hand)>2:
                pair_hand.append(pair_kickers[-1])
                pair_hand.append(pair_kickers[-2])
                pair_hand.append(pair_kickers[-3])
            player_hand_type="Pair"
            player_hand_value=hand_rankings[player_hand_type]
            global player_has_pair, player_pair_value, player_pair_kickers
            player_has_pair=True
            player_pair_value=pair_pair[-1].value
            if len(hand)>2:
                player_pair_kickers=[pair_kickers[-1].value,pair_kickers[-2].value,pair_kickers[-3].value]
            else:
                pass
            has_hand=True
            player_hand=pair_hand
            player_hand_string=f"A Pair of {pair_pair[-1].rank}s"
            break
        else:
            high_card_hand=[]
            high_card_hand.append(hand[-1])
            high_card_hand.append(hand[-2])
            if len(hand)>2:
                high_card_hand.append(hand[-3])
                high_card_hand.append(hand[-4])
                high_card_hand.append(hand[-5])
            else:
                pass
            high_card_hand.sort(key=lambda high_card_hand:high_card_hand.value)
            player_hand_type="High Card"
            player_hand_value=hand_rankings[player_hand_type]
            global player_has_high_card, player_high_card_value, player_high_card_kickers
            player_has_high_card=True
            player_high_card_value=high_card_hand[-1].value
            if len(hand)>2:
                player_high_card_kickers=[high_card_hand[-2].value,high_card_hand[-3].value,high_card_hand[-4].value,high_card_hand[-5].value]
            else:
                pass
            has_hand=True
            player_hand=high_card_hand
            player_hand_string=f"High Card-{high_card_hand[-1].rank}"
            break
```

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I would do to improve this code is to add a docstring and some unit tests.  With the `doctest` module, the unit tests can be included within the docstring, helping demonstrate the expected result from the function.

For example:

```
    """
    Return the highest-scoring poker hand from HAND.

    >>> player_hand_value_check(hand("8♥ T♠ J♠ Q♠ K♥ K♠ A♠"))
    straight_flush("A")
    >>> player_hand_value_check(hand("A♠ 2♥ 3♥ 4♥ 5♥ K♣ K♦"))
    straight("5")
    >>> player_hand_value_check(hand("2♠ 2♥ 3♥ 4♥ 5♥ K♣ K♦"))
    two_pair("K", "2", "5")
    ⋮ 
    """
```

Eliminate global variables - instead of manipulating those in the function, return a suitable object (as in example above) which knows how to compare against other hands and can format itself into a string.

Look at what actions are repeated, and extract those as functions.  For example, we could have a function that extracts the cards of the most numerous suit and a function that finds a straight - these can be combined to detect a straight flush.

Similarly, if we have functions to find pairs and trips, we can combine those to find two-pair and full house.

Comment: Thanks for that. For a docstring would a print statement showing that it's working as normal be enough or does it need more? Also i made a function that automated putting the cards into a list and checking the suits to detect a flush but then what was happening was that if the hand had a flush, it would get stuck in an infinite loop at the royal flush section and I couldn't figure out why, do you have any ideas what might have caused that? Thanks again.

Comment: I've added an example of using doctest.  If you have problems making your code work, then I can't guess what you did wrong.  If you can't solve the problem, you should create a _minimal_ reproducible example from that part and ask for help over at [so].  But try hard to fix it yourself first - start by adding tests of the helper functions, to confirm that they work correctly.